# PostgreSQL: Replace schema in db1 with schema from db2

Tags: postgresql, replication

Is there a way to replace data in a schema in db1 with data in a schema in db2, given that the schemas are identical (only the data differs)? An alternative would be to replace the whole schema? I would like to keep the name of the schema in db1.

I've searched the documentation but can't find any solution. Any ideas?

Comment: [Logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html)

Comment: That could work, thanks. Do you know if it's possible to execute the transaction of data manually? For example if I would use my test db as Publisher and I want to transfer to my subscriptor (original db) only some specific data when some changes are made?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   The built in pub/sub implementation of logical replication enforces the same schema name.

Comment: How about `pg_dump -n ...`, followed by import, then drop the old schema cascading, and renaming the new schema to have the name of the old one?

Comment: Yes maybe that's the simplest solution, thanks. Will try it!